# Слова "тапочки", "туфли", "кроссовки" в словаре

Tags: лексикография

Начальная форма существительных - им.п. ед.ч. Почему слова "тапочки", "туфли", "кроссовки" в словаре даются не в начальной форме, как другие существительные?

Comment: Предполагаю,  потому, что обозначают парные предметы. Но это не достаточное основание. Ведь есть форма ед. ч.? Есть!

Answer (score 2):

Предметы, как правило используемые в форме множественного числа (особенно парные), в заголовках словарных статей традиционно приводятся именно в этой форме. Хотя бывают и исключения, орфоэпические словари, например.

Comment: Понимаю, но все равно нелогично. Хотелось бы от лексикографов  ожидать соблюдение  ими же придуманных правил (слова в словаре располагаются в начальной форме).

Comment: А что такое "начальная форма"?  
Один сапог - это сапог и ничего более. Два сапога - пара. А **сапоги** - это обувь. Не просто пять левых и три правых, а именно - парный предмет, без пары смысла особо не имеющий. И кто из сапогов начальнее? Случай одноногого сапогоносителя исключим пока.

Тоже, например, с пельменями. Один пельмень - пельмень. Два пельменя - это даже не пара. А **пельмени** - кушанье.